# Padding is removed for just before transitioning

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a navbar that shrinks using intersection observer that adds a class accordingly but when the transition starts, it starts from 0 padding.

Here right when the .nav-scrolled is added, the CSS properties are also added to the nav bar. But right when it adds, the padding starts transitioning from 0. What can I do?

```js
const nav = document.querySelector("nav");
const sectionOne = document.querySelector(".intersection");

const sectionOneObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, sectionOneObserver) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      nav.classList.add("nav-scrolled")
    } else {
      nav.classList.remove("nav-scrolled")
    }
  });
});

sectionOneObserver.observe(sectionOne)
```

```css
.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  padding-block: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

nav>* {
  margin-inline: 5%;
}

nav>div {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-block: 10px;
}

.nav-scrolled {
  width: 80%;
  padding-block: 15px;
  font-size: 20%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transform: translateY(15px);
}

.nav-scrolled>* {
  margin-inline: 15px;
}
.intersection{height:10vh}

.body{color:red; height:120vh}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
  <nav>
    <a href="#">
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <h2>Heading-2</h2>
    </a>
    
    <div>
      <a href="#">link1</a>
      <a href="#">link2</a>
      <a href="#">link3</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="intersection"></div>
<div class="body"><div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that the padding starts from 0. This happens because you have `margin-inline` on the children of the nav element. This margin disappears when you scroll and the children don't have a transition-tag, so that's why it appears to be jumping. I just removed this css-line. Seems to work just fine :)

```js
const nav = document.querySelector("nav");
const sectionOne = document.querySelector(".intersection");

const sectionOneObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, sectionOneObserver) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      nav.classList.add("nav-scrolled")
    } else {
      nav.classList.remove("nav-scrolled")
    }
  });
});

sectionOneObserver.observe(sectionOne)
```

```css
.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  padding-block: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

nav>* {
  margin-inline: 5%;
}

nav>div {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-block: 10px;
}

.nav-scrolled {
  width: 80%;
  padding-block: 15px;
  font-size: 20%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transform: translateY(15px);
}

.intersection{height:10vh}

.body{color:red; height:120vh}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
  <nav>
    <a href="#">
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <h2>Heading-2</h2>
    </a>
    
    <div>
      <a href="#">link1</a>
      <a href="#">link2</a>
      <a href="#">link3</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="intersection"></div>
<div class="body"><div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with the `.nav-scrolled>*` selector.  It's the property change on this that is causing the jump. It's easier to see this when the transition is extended to be `5s` long.

The problem is happening because you do not have a `transition` applied on `nav>*` even though you are changing properties when scrolled, thus an immediate jump with no transition visible.  The fix is to move your transition to apply to both the parent `.nav` selector and the `nav>*` selector, like this:

```css
nav,
nav>* {
  transition: 5s ease;
}
```

```js
const nav = document.querySelector("nav");
const sectionOne = document.querySelector(".intersection");

const sectionOneObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, sectionOneObserver) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      nav.classList.add("nav-scrolled")
    } else {
      nav.classList.remove("nav-scrolled")
    }
  });
});

sectionOneObserver.observe(sectionOne)
```

```css
.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  padding-block: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

nav>* {
  margin-inline: 5%;
}

nav,
nav>* {
  transition: 5s ease;
}

nav>div {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-block: 10px;
}

.nav-scrolled {
  width: 80%;
  padding-block: 15px;
  font-size: 20%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transform: translateY(15px);
}

.nav-scrolled>* {
  margin-inline: 15px;
}
.intersection{height:10vh}

.body{color:red; height:120vh}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
  <nav>
    <a href="#">
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <h2>Heading-2</h2>
    </a>
    
    <div>
      <a href="#">link1</a>
      <a href="#">link2</a>
      <a href="#">link3</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="intersection"></div>
<div class="body"><div>
```